# In Erlang how do I convert a String to a binary value?

Tags: erlang

In Erlang how do I convert a `string` to a `binary` value?

```
String = "Hello"
%% should be
Binary = <<"Hello">>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In Erlang strings are represented as a list of integers. You can therefore use the `list_to_binary` (built-in-function, aka BIF). Here is an example I ran in the Erlang console (started with `erl`):

```
1> list_to_binary("hello world").
<<"hello world">>
```

Comment: Thanks. My brain wasn't working and I kept doing "string_to_binary" in a desperate attempt to prove the documentation, google, and common sense wrong. :)

Comment: I also enter `string_to_binary` quite often, but the compiler keeps remaining me that there isn't such a thing ;)

Comment: You will also want to keep in mind what happens when the string contains non-ASCII characters. Some function from the `unicode` module might be more appropriate than list_to_binary for such occasions.

Comment: It work only if string contain 1 byte char, else
81> list_to_binary("hello брбр"). ** exception error: bad argument in function list_to_binary/1 called as list_to_binary([104,101,108,108,111,32,1073,1088,1073,1088])
82>

Answer (score 8):

the unicode (utf-8/16/32) character set needs more number of bits to express characters that are greater than 1-byte in length:
   this is why the above call failed for any byte value > 255 (the limit of information that a byte can hold, and which is sufficient for IS0-8859/ASCII/Latin1)

to correctly handle unicode characters you'd need to use

`unicode:characters_to_binary()   R1[(N>3)]`

instead, which can handle both Latin1 AND unicode encoding.

HTH ...