# how to convert String to bytes in Erlang

Tags: erlang, smpp

I am trying to implement SMPP protocol using Erlang and I have hit a dead end trying to convert string e.g. username and password to bytes in order to come up with a PDU to send over to the SMSC. All the search and reading various materials has not helped.

Kindly advice on a way I can achieve this.

Comment: You should specify which encoding you want to generate, otherwise it's hard to help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Erlang how do I convert a String to a binary value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268828/in-erlang-how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-binary-value)

Answer (score 11):

Probably the first thing to note that there's no special type for strings in Erlang. So strings in Erlang actually represented as lists of integers:

```
1> [116, 101, 115, 116].
"test"
```

So keeping that in mind your question is actually transformed to "how to convert list of integers to bytes". And now it's should pretty straightforward with [list_to_binary/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_binary-1) function for strings with 8-bit characters:

```
1> list_to_binary("test").
<<"test">>
2> list_to_binary([0, 255]).
<<0,255>>
```

However if you have an Unicode string [list_to_binary/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_binary-1) will raise `badarg` error (*note also how original string represented in the error message*):

```
1> list_to_binary("тест").
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  list_to_binary/1
        called as list_to_binary([1090,1077,1089,1090])
```

And in this case functions from [unicode](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html) module can be used. For example to convert Unicode string to UTF-8 binary [unicode:characters_to_binary/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_binary-3) (*there are also* [unicode:characters_to_binary/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_binary-1) *and* [unicode:characters_to_binary/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_binary-2)) can be used:

```
1> unicode:characters_to_binary("тест", unicode, utf8).
<<209,130,208,181,209,129,209,130>>
```